# MouseProc (WH_MOUSE) events firing twice

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I want to ask a question regarding a problem I've been experiencing.

I install a **WH_MOUSE** hook using the following function:

```
hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, (HOOKPROC)MouseHookProc, dllInstance, threadId);
```

The **threadId** is obtained using **GetWindowThreadProcessId** function. This is successful, because the hook only works in the process that I want it to. The **dllInstance** is obtained from a **DllMain** entry point. For what it's worth, the **hMouseHook** is in a shared data segment (**#pragma data_seg(".shared")**). The following code shows the **MouseHookProc** that is provided in the above **SetWindowsHookEx** call:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode < 0 || !isRunning())
        return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    switch (wParam) {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: {
            OutputDebugStringA("Mouse button down!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

While testing, **isRunning()** returns **TRUE** (I double checked). My problem is that the "Mouse button down!" message is printed twice each time the left mouse button is held down. Why, given the provided code, does this happen? I am currently using a workaround, but would like to understand why this happens.

I debug the launcher program (the one that calls the DLL's function containing **SetWindowsHookEx**) in Visual Studio 2015 and attach it to the process I'm using (Debug -> Attach to Process).

Thanks in advance for any responses.

**Edit: it seems only the first time the procedure is called nCode == HC_ACTION. I guess this is an answer to my question, but I would like to know why my procedure is called a second time with nCode == HC_NOREMOVE?**

Comment: My expectation is that the `HC_NOREMOVE` call (`PeekMessage` called with `PM_NOREMOVE`) to be first.  I don't know why it is the second call.  You can probably just ignore any call with the `HC_NOREMOVE` flag.

Comment: it is entirely normal and [documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644988(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Actually, I just shamefully assumed that it was second, without checking. You are correct, HC_NOREMOVE is the first. Now my question remains, why does my procedure get called with a HC_NOREMOVE message? What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: @Hans Passant I know the codes are documented, but where can I find information on the purpose of the HC_NOREMOVE message code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called once with nCode == HC_NOREMOVE and then again with nCode == HC_ACTION.